# Buddypress Xprofile fields & Wordpress custom user meta 2 way sync

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I am working a wordpress + buddypress based eCommerce site which has marketpress plugin installed to handle the ecommerce part. The problem i am running into is that both wordpress usermeta and buddypress x-profile fields are not integrated with each other by design.

Within my current setup, users can register using buddypress sign-up and fill in their profile information and edit it as well.
I am trying to get the buddypress profile information to be in sync with Wordpress custom usermeta fields i created so that the buddypress profile information can be used within plugins like marketpress (which relies on wordpress user meta to populate shipping fields for a logged in user). Are there any buddypress & wordpress hooks which can be used here to setup a two way sync between buddypress xprofile and wordpresss user meta fields?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dashboard under 'Settings > BuddyPress > Profile Settings' have you selected "Enable BuddyPress to WordPress profile syncing" ?

I think that it only syncs  full names and email addresses.

The available syncing functions are found in 
buddypress\bp-xprofile\bp-xprofile-functions.php

- function xprofile_sync_wp_profile()
- function xprofile_sync_bp_profile()

Perhaps the hooks used there will help you write a function to push BP profile fields to usermeta. But it might be easier to change MarketPress to pull from BP rather than WP.